# Will adding "www." to my domain setting in Google Analytics impact already collected data?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, htaccess, analytics, drupal

I have a profile in Google Analytics (GA) that has been collecting data for a year. The domain setting in GA is "http://example.com". The site, however, will redirect any non-www request, to www.example.com, via a typical .htaccess refinement.

The source problem I'm trying to fix is that In-Page analytics does not load. When accessing In-Page analytics in the new GA, I get the following error:

> We've identified problems in your setup. These may cause problems
>   loading In-Page Analytics. Your site doesn't load ga.js from Google.
>   If you host the Google tracking code on your own servers, it isn't
>   updated automatically and can miss important changes. We didn't find a
>   tracking snippet on your site. In-Page Analytics cannot load. Please
>   make sure you have tracking installed correctly. If your snippet is
>   included in a separate JavaScript file, you'll have to manually check
>   it is being loaded correctly.

When loading In-Page Analytics in full screen mode -- visting the domain directly -- I get:

> Access denied. Please try relaunching In-Page Analytics from the report.

After researching the issue online, I've found the following proposed fixes:

1. Log out of the target site when using GA, in the case your site doesn't load the tracking codes for logged in users (our current Drupal configuration indeed does this)
2. Clearing cache
3. Clearing cookies - specifically the GASO cookie
4. Ensuring your GA domain setting uses www if your site redirects to www forcefully

I've tried items 1-3 and the have not addressed the issue. I would like to try #4, but want to make sure this change won't impact data I've already collected and that GA will consider all data collected before and after the change as the same site.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the setting of your tag to '[one domain with multiple sub-domains](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html)'.

I'd try that first because if you change the domain setting in the way you suggest GA will preserve your existing data, but will track all the 'new' urls separately. You may be better off preserving the existing profile and beginning a new one.