# Google Analytics www 301 causing issues with In-Page Analytics

Tags: google, analytics, 301-redirect

The closest question I could find to my problem is [this one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27281/will-adding-www-to-my-domain-setting-in-google-analytics-impact-already-colle). The similarity is:

> I have a profile in Google Analytics (GA) that has been collecting data for a year. The domain setting in GA is `http://example.com`. The site, however, will redirect any non-www request, to `www.example.com`, via a typical .htaccess refinement.

We do this to keep the traffic on the load balancers. I don't know the method the original user had in place, but we're doing a 301 on any `no-www` to the `www` equivalent. I believe this has to be somewhat standard. Where I differ from this question is in the error message I receive when trying to load the In-Page Analytics? I'm instead receiving:

> Error: The Website in your settings (`http://example.com`), redirects into a different domain. (`http://www.example.com`). In-Page Analytics currently works on only one domain. Note that `www.example.com` and `example.com` are NOT considered to be on the same domain. Also, make sure you're not redirecting from http:// to https:// or vice versa.

I understand what's being explained, it just seems as though this can't be the end-all.  I tried updating the Analytics settings, which from day one has been set as "One domain with multiple subdomains", but I don't see any options to change the URL (which is currently set to `http://example.com` and not `http://www.example.com`). I'd prefer not to have to change the URL if that was at all possible, but I can't seem to find any documentation or anything that provide any possible solutions.

Comment: Can you provide an anonymized copy (strip `UA-` info and domains) of the analytics snippet you're using to collect data? (please include In-Page Analytics calls)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/F25ZRzds  . My apologies, I'm not sure what you mean by " (please include In-Page Analytics calls) ". I'm trying to access the In-Page function in the Google Analytics dashboard

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - wanted to ensure that any applicable code was included in case you were referring to event tracking for named anchors on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be a limitation of Google Analytics' reporting capabilities - as hinted in the error message, "In-Page Analytics *currently* works on only one domain", so it appears to be something they're working on.

The workaround is to change the site's URL in your profile settings ([Admin > Profile Settings > Website URL](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1010249)) - changing this value, however, this does not appear to affect reporting across multiple subdomains (and does not require any changes to your site's tracking snippet).

Comment: Thank you, changing the Website URL did the trick, and didn't affect any of the already processed data. Thank you again.